# It it acceptable to ask questions that have arisen from another answer

Tags: discussion, iterative-review

It it acceptable to ask questions that have arisen from another answer, repeatedly.

For example...

1. I post working code and ask to have it reviewed.
2. Someone answers with some suggestions.
3. I re-write the code, and as it is so different from the original code, I post if for review as a separate question.
4. Then, because I have not fully understood the suggestions as they are perhaps quite general, someone offers some more advice to better structure the code.

This keeps going on and on until eventually there is a whole load of questions that all build on each other and I have a well structured solution that relied very heavily on the Code Review Q&A site.

Comment: IMO you're walking on the fence with *design questions* - we review *working, implemented code*, not hypothetical, high-level designs. "The code is the design": we review design when the code we see is organized in such a way that properly addressing code issues implies revisiting the whole design, e.g. a WPF application where OP would have implemented everything in the code-behind - reviews are very likely to direct the OP towards a MVVM pattern, for example. Can you clarify what you mean with "questions about a design in your head"? These would be off-topic.

Comment: I have re-written the question

Comment: Do [*How to post a follow-up question?*](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1065/23788) and [*Is code ever clean enough? - Can there be too many follow-up questions?*](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6050/23788) answer your question?