# How many questions with same script can I ask, if code not only merged reviews but adds new functionality

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, iterative-review

How many questions with same script can I ask, if code not only merged reviews but adds new functionality?
Can I submit part of code(fully working part with new code) together with full code or without(but with github link)?
Will it make users bored? :)

It's bash script, not most popular on this site.

Not a duplicate: Script is very different from review to review, so if it will be in one question should answers be deleted instead of thanks people(with accepting answer and probably vote up)

Comment: To answer your questions: 1. You can ask as many questions as you want, unless it's _exactly the same code_. 2. Yes you can submit as much or little as you want. 3. No

Comment: Your 2nd answer doesn't really answer the question though, since just a GH link is unacceptable.

Comment: Possible dupplicate of [Is code ever clean enough? - Can there be too many follow-up questions?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6050/31562) (unfortunately I can't vote on this as I would then hammer-close it)

Comment: @SimonForsberg I read suggested duplicates and decide to post merged with review version as one more answer, and version with significant changes as another question in 48 hours or more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How many questions with same script can I ask, if code not only merged reviews but adds new functionality?

If it has new functionality (or even when it doesn't but it has been rewritten significantly enough to be new code), there's no problem with posting a new version. We've seen questions with 5 versions of the same program, every time a bit better.

> Can I submit part of code(fully working part with new code) together with full code or without(but with github link)?

With the full code, yes. Links are acceptable for bonus context, but everything you want to have reviewed has to be included in the question itself. Not behind links.

> Will it make users bored? :)

Perhaps, perhaps not. If you put in the effort to improve your code and listen to the answers provided, I'm sure there are enough people willing to put in the effort to help out.

Just make sure you leave a couple of days (a good rule of thumb is to wait at least 48 hours, preferably more) between posting revisions. More answers might be incoming after all.

Comment: It's not just about more answers that might be incoming, but also that people might get sick of all the follow-up questions, see janos' answer to this related question: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6056/31562